# How to create resource for not for every module in terraform?

Tags: terraform

So I've got a common module that has:

```
module "foo1" {
  source            = "./modules/bar"
  name              = "foo1"
  id                = "123"
}

module "foo2" {
  source            = "./modules/bar"
  name              = "foo2"
  id                = "456"
}
```

```
// module bar
resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  account_id = var.name
  ...
}
```

that is being referenced by 2 other modules as you can see above. The thing is this module bar generates a resource with an email: `google_service_account.service_account.email` that I'd like to use to create a bunch of other resources but I only want to create them for `foo1` and not for `foo2` (`bar` module uses both `name` and `id` vars to generate the email). How can I exclude `foo2` from creating resource from?

```
// needs to be created using the email generated for `foo1` only
resource "google_project_iam_member" "admin" {
  ...
  member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account.email}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you could use [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/meta-arguments/count.html) to conditionally create your project:

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "admin" {
 
  count = var.name == "foo1" ? 1 : 0

  ...
  member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account.email}"
}
```

The above will create `google_project_iam_member.admin` when `name` is `foo1`.